# Djangoでstripeのcheck_out_sessionが開かれない

Tags: python, html, django

djangoでstripeが実行されません。
ページを開いたときに読みこずhome.htmlのボタンを押してもfetchを読み込みません。
なぜ、プロジェクト直下のurlが読み込まれているかわかりません。
jsのルーティングがおかしいのか見当がつかず質問させていただきました。

##### ターミナルのエラー

```
"GET /subscription/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1496
Not Found: /config/
```

Chrome拡張のNetworkを開くと以下の内容が表示されます。

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/config/
Using the URLconf defined in sample_app.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
accounts/
signup/ [name='signup']
activate/<uidb64>/<token>/ [name='activate']
subscription/
The current path, config/, didn't match any of these.
```

プロジェクト直下のurls.pyは下記です。

##### project/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from sample import views 


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', login_required(TemplateView.as_view(template_name='registration/index.html'))),
    path("signup/", views.SignUpView.as_view(), name="signup"),
    path('activate/<uidb64>/<token>/', views.ActivateView.as_view(), name='activate'),
    path('subscription/', include('subscription.urls')),
```

```
{% load static %}
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>  <!-- new -->
        <script src="{% static 'main.js' %}"></script> <!-- new -->
        
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">サブスク</a>
        </nav>
        <div class="container mt-4">
        {% block main %}
        <p>※{{user }}ようこそ</p>
        {% endblock %}
        
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

##### home.html

```
{% extends "subscription/base.html" %}

{% block main %}
<p>{{ user }}様</p>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitBtn">会員</button>
    
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

##### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from sample_app.settings import AUTH_USER_MODEL
from subscription.models import Stripe_Customer
 
User = AUTH_USER_MODEL


from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


from django.http.response import JsonResponse, HttpResponse  
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt 
from django.conf import settings 
import stripe 


@csrf_exempt
def create_checkout_session(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        domain_url = 'http://localhost:8000/'
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        try:
            checkout_session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
                client_reference_id=request.user.id if request.user.is_authenticated else None,
                success_url=domain_url + 'success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
                cancel_url=domain_url + 'cancel/',
                payment_method_types=['card'],
                mode='subscription',
                line_items=[
                    {
                        'price': settings.STRIPE_PRICE_ID,
                        'quantity': 1,
                    }
                ]
            )
            return JsonResponse({'sessionId': checkout_session['id']})
        except Exception as e:
            return JsonResponse({'error': str(e)})

@csrf_exempt
def stripe_config(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        stripe_config = {'publicKey': settings.STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY}
        return JsonResponse(stripe_config, safe=False)


@csrf_exempt
def stripe_webhook(request):
    stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
    endpoint_secret = settings.STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET
    payload = request.body
    sig_header = request.META['HTTP_STRIPE_SIGNATURE']
    event = None

    try:
        event = stripe.Webhook.construct_event(
            payload, sig_header, endpoint_secret
        )
    except ValueError as e:
        # Invalid payload
        return HttpResponse(status=400)
    except stripe.error.SignatureVerificationError as e:
        # Invalid signature
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    # Handle the checkout.session.completed event
    if event['type'] == 'checkout.session.completed':
        session = event['data']['object']

        # Fetch all the required data from session
        client_reference_id = session.get('client_reference_id')
        stripe_customer_id = session.get('customer')
        stripe_subscription_id = session.get('subscription')

        # Get the user and create a new StripeCustomer
        user = User.objects.get(id=client_reference_id)
        Stripe_Customer.objects.create(
            user=user,
            stripeCustomerId=stripe_customer_id,
            stripeSubscriptionId=stripe_subscription_id,
        )
        print(user.username + ' just subscribed.')

    return HttpResponse(status=200)

#--------------------------------



#-------index_view-----------
@method_decorator(login_required,name="dispatch")
class IndexView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "subscription/home.html"
    model = Stripe_Customer


#-------Success_view-----------

class SuccessView(TemplateView):
   template_name = "subscription/success.html"
   
#-------Cancel_view-----------
class CancelView(TemplateView):
   template_name = "subscription/cancel.html"
```

##### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from subscription import views 

app_name ="subscription"

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('config/', views.stripe_config),
    path('create-checkout-session/', views.create_checkout_session),
    path('success/', views.SuccessView.as_view(), name='success'),
    path('cancel/', views.CancelView.as_view(), name='cancel'),

]
```

##### static/main.js

```
console.log("Sanity check!");

// Get Stripe publishable key
fetch("config/")
.then((result) => { return result.json(); })
.then((data) => {
  // Initialize Stripe.js
  const stripe = Stripe(data.publicKey);

  // new
  // Event handler
  let submitBtn = document.querySelector("#submitBtn");
  if (submitBtn !== null) {
    submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    // Get Checkout Session ID
    fetch("/create-checkout-session/")
      .then((result) => { return result.json(); })
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        // Redirect to Stripe Checkout
        return stripe.redirectToCheckout({sessionId: data.sessionId})
      })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      });
    });
  }
});
```

参考URL
https://testdriven.io/blog/django-stripe-subscriptions/

Comment: 回答のついた質問を編集して中身を空にするのは止めましょう

Answer (score 1, accepted):

まず、js側の`fetch`でリクエストしようとしている`"config/"`は`urls.py`に見当たりません。

`main.js`でやろうとしていることを踏まえると、リクエスト先は`/subscription/config/`が正しいように見えます。